# Is there any risk in placing a scan of a diploma online?

Tags: privacy, academia

I wonder whether there is any risk in placing a scan of one's diploma online.

Comment: what information is on the diploma?

Answer (score 3):

Not particularly.

The diploma itself isn't supposed to be a secure document, and is given to people to post on walls, not to present as verification of a degree.  [A quick google image search](https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1600&bih=666&q=diploma&oq=diploma&gs_l=img.3..0l10.2082.3744.0.4168.7.7.0.0.0.0.355.698.3-2.2.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..5.2.696.BrA8-SDV3_Q#tbm=isch&q=college%20diploma) reveals that many, many people have posted copies of their diploma's on the internet, so it's not like this would be a rare commodity.  Degree verification is done directly through the college/university, not through diplomas.

As long as you're comfortable revealing personal details of your life to everyone, I see no reason not to post a diploma.  Keep in mind that posting personal details about yourself makes you a bit more vulnerable to Con-men who can try to convince you to trust them based on this.  i.e. casually mentioning they went to the same school and got the same degree as you just a few years before/after you did.

Comment: I agree with the answer - although "many people on the internet do this so it must be safe" can be hilariously wrong: https://twitter.com/needadebitcard

Comment: @cloudfeet You misread my comment.  It's not "people do it so it must be safe".  It's "People do it, so there's already a readily available source for diplomas for anyone who wants to to exploit them.  One more is unlikely to be of any real value.".

Comment: Ah right - my mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Someone could of course copy & paste it, edit the fields, whatever. You have the original and are thus able to prove that you have it. I know some personal websites where people have posted their certs and diplomas and even though I wouldn't do it myself, there are no security or privacy flaws here.